# Passive voice on a song´s lyrics

Tags: passive-voice

On Adele´s song "Someone like you" there´s a part that says "Bound by the surprise of our glory days". Is it an actual Passive voice?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence from the [lyrics](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/adele/someonelikeyou.html) is:

> We were born and raised / In a summer haze / bound by the surprise / Of our glory days .

The (implied) subject of "bound" is "we" so this is not a passive construction.

In any case, attempting grammatical analysis of popular song lyrics is often frustrating and of little benefit. Songwriters will freely violate grammatical rules to achieve rhythm, rhyme, and emotional effect. They may not even care about clarity of meaning.

Just to be clear, this particular lyric is not ungrammatical, and being in the passive voice certainly does not make any test ungrammatical, or in any way wrong. But song lyrics are often poor examples of English usage, and sometiems questiosn about them are of limited value here on ELL for that reason.

Comment: Plus there's nothing wrong with the passive voice in the first place. Even if this were such an example, it wouldn't be violating anything.

Comment: @Jason Bassford  neither the questioner nor I said that there was anything wrong with using the passive voice. One might want to identify when it is being used without wanting to avoid it as an error. A recent answer of mine (https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/211818/)  gives my views on the use of the passive voice rather fully.

Comment: But wouldnt it be "We were bound by the surprise"? And if Im not wrong (at least following the example I looked) it would be passive like

Comment: @Audryplier Hmm on a second look, this might be a passive construction, with the active form being "the surprise bound us". If so, it only goes to demonstrate that in some cases passive constructions are superior.

Comment: @DavidSiegel You discussed the sentence, passive constructions, and then said that "songwriters will freely violate grammatical rules." What I'm saying is that even if it *is* passive, that is *not* a violation of grammar rules.

Comment: @ Jason Bassford No there is no violation here.and I didn't intend to imply that there was one. Merely that questions about the grammer of song lyrics are a bit dubious, because one cannot safely assume that they are correct, or good examples. I have edited my answer to try to make this clear.